# How do I parse string timestamps of different length to time?

Tags: go, timestamp

I have a slice of values holding timestamps of different length.
Most of them look like this:

```
2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z
```

but some of them are shorter:

```
2006-01-02T15:04:05.00000Z
2006-01-02T15:04:05.0000Z
```

If I do:

```
str := dataSlice[j][0].(string)
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
```

I get errors like:

```
parsing time "2016-10-23T02:38:45.25986Z" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z": cannot parse "" as ".000000"
parsing time "2016-10-23T21:43:59.0175Z" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z": cannot parse ".0175Z" as ".000000"
```

I want to parse them exactly like they originally are.
How can I dynamically switch the layout corresponding to the length?
(And why do the error messages differ?)

Comment: Are the fractional portions all `0`s, or do you need sub-second resolution if they're not? It would be easy to just strip that out of the string on all timestamps before parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not all `0` s, samples: `2016-07-04T09:30:33.031979Z` `2016-10-23T22:01:01.41305Z` `2016-10-23T14:50:55.0671Z`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For time layouts, if the fractional seconds are optional, use `9` instead of `0` in the layout.  For example, `2006-01-02T15:04:05.00000Z` matches only times with 5 digits after the decimal place.  However, `2006-01-02T15:04:05.9Z` matches a time with *any* number of digits after the decimal, including zero.

https://play.golang.org/p/QMD28aqv9E

The [Time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) documentation provides examples, the last one of which explains this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `000000` with `999999`:

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999Z"
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Wd7kXIpoWO.